# Why is exterior paint cracking just a month after application?

Tags: paint, exterior, damage

Sunny wall was recently painted by a professional with primer and two coats of exterior paint.

Areas with cracks were sanded but primer was applied over old paint where in seemingly good shape.

Just a month later cracks are appearing.

Is this due to some poor application or something wrong with the siding?

Comment: Can you expand on the preparation?  Is the new paint cracking over where the old cracks were?   And do you know what the old paint was?   Also, are there dark colours involved here (they tend to get a lot warmer due to insolation)

Comment: It might be a good idea to query the pro who did the work too.

Comment: Was the surface scraped? Cracks are one thing but if the paint is lose primer won’t stop it from cracking when there are cracks there are usually some chips that are shall we say flexible. scraping breaks these lose if not scraped or at least pressure washed ? If not this may well be the reason the paint is cracking.

Comment: post some photos.